# Visual Studio 2012: No source available - There is no source code available for the current location

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working in a WPF app using:

- C#
- .Net 4.0
- MVVM Light v5.3 (Installed via NuGet)
- MahApps.Metro v1.3 (Installed via NuGet)

While I'm debugging the app, I get an error in the lines that call methods of MVVM Light or MahApps.Metro.

For MVVM Light, here's the code:

```
public List<string> validation_errors
{
    get
    {
        return _validation_errors;
    }
    set
    {
        _validation_errors = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("validation_errors");
    }
}
```

And this is the error message:

**No source available**

There is no source code available for the current location.

**Call stack location:**

GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll!GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObersvableObject.RaisePropertyChanged(strinh propertyName) Line 195

**Source file information:**

```
Locating source for 'D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\ObservableObject.cs'. (No checksum.)
The file 'D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\ObservableObject.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\ObservableObject.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\ObservableObject.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\ObservableObject.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\ObservableObject.cs'.
```

This is the code for MahApps.Metro:

```
_dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(this, Resources.lang.information_message, Resources.lang.data_saved, MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative);
```

And this is the error message for MahApps.Metro:

**No source available**

There is no source code available for the current location.

**Call stack location:**

MahApps.Metro.dll!MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.DialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(object context, string title, string message, MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.MessageDialogStyle style, MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.MetroDialogSettings settings) Line 40

**Source file information:**

```
Locating source for 'd:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro\Controls\Dialogs\DialogCoordinator.cs'. (No checksum.)
The file 'd:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro\Controls\Dialogs\DialogCoordinator.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'd:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro\Controls\Dialogs\DialogCoordinator.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'd:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro\Controls\Dialogs\DialogCoordinator.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: d:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro\Controls\Dialogs\DialogCoordinator.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'd:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro\Controls\Dialogs\DialogCoordinator.cs'.
```

What I've tried:

I found a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901736/mvvm-light-obtained-via-nuget-relaycommand-cs-not-found). I've tried enabling the option:

```
Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Just My Code
```

But I had no luck.

What else can I try in order to get rid of the interruptions due the missing source code? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked namespaces' consistency between xaml and cs?

Comment: If you want to look at source code files then you need to compile it from the actual source code and not use the Nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't want to look at the source code files, I just want to pass for the lines while debugging without being interrupted by the annoying "No source available" message.