# C# Visual Studio 2012: No source available

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

In my project (WebSite) I have installed via `nuget` the `CM.sms.dll` but when code reaches this line:

```
SmsGatewayClient smsGateway = new SmsGatewayClient();
```

I get a `No source available` error:

> Locating source for 'c:\dev\SMS\CM.Sms.Server.Client\CM.Sms.Server.HttpMTGateway.Client\CM.Sms.Gateway.NugetPackage\CM.Sms\SmsGatewayClient.cs'.
>   The file 'c:\dev\SMS\CM.Sms.Server.Client\CM.Sms.Server.HttpMTGateway.Client\CM.Sms.Gateway.NugetPackage\CM.Sms\SmsGatewayClient.cs' does not exist.
>   Looking in script documents for 'c:\dev\SMS\CM.Sms.Server.Client\CM.Sms.Server.HttpMTGateway.Client\CM.Sms.Gateway.NugetPackage\CM.Sms\SmsGatewayClient.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for 'c:\dev\SMS\CM.Sms.Server.Client\CM.Sms.Server.HttpMTGateway.Client\CM.Sms.Gateway.NugetPackage\CM.Sms\SmsGatewayClient.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.

I've tried enabling the option:

Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Just My Code 
But no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVVM Light obtained via NuGet - RelayCommand.cs not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16901736/11683)

Comment: @GSerg I tried the solution: `Go to Tools-Options...-Debugging-General and tick Enable Just My Code ` but with no luck